# Parent parameter used as Child Class in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, inheritance, parent-child

I have an HttpPost method where I'd like to be able to pass a Parent Class as parameter.
From that parent class, I have 4 derived classes.
The goal is to use only one HttpPost method to add any of these derived classes to the DB. Is this something possible ?

I tried passing the Parent Class as parameter but then I'm losing all the attributes specific to the derived class.

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> AddCustomField(CustomField customField)
{
    // customField could be NumberCustomField, DropdownCustomField, StringCustomField, ...

    // This allows me to get a NumberCustomField but I lose all the attributes specific to the derived class
    NumberCustomField numberCustomField = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NumberCustomField>(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(customField));

    // This triggers an exception
    NumberCustomField numberCustomField = (NumberCustomField) customField;

    // I'd like to add any of the derived class to the DB, inheritance is set in the context (with a discriminator)
    _context.CustomFields.Add(numberCustomField); 

    return Ok();
}
```

Here's my client side code :

```js
// Form data structure sent to the back-end
const initialCustomField = {
    label: '',
    type: null, // 'number', 'text', 'list' => used as discriminator
    category: 'tree',
    isGlobal: true,
    min: '0', // Specific to NumberCustomField
    max: '',
    step: '1',
    maxLength: '256', // Specific to StringCustomField
    isMultiple: false, // Specific to DropdownCustomField
    isNumeric: false,
    dropdownCustomFieldValues: [{ label: '', value: '' }]
};

// Axios request
static addCustomField(customField) {
    return Axios.post(BACKEND_ENDPOINT + 'customFields/', customField, {
        headers: { 'Authorization': `Bearer ${new Cookies().get('token')}` }
    }).then(response => {
        return response.data;
    }, () => {
        return;
    });
}
```

Should I use 4 different HttpPost methods or is it achievable ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: What's the client side of your post look like?

Comment: Hello, @psiodrake ! I edited my post so that you can see the client-side code. The "type" attribute determines what specific field the user will have to complete

Comment: I think it good to use one POST method for each entity you have, but if you want to use one HTTP method you can add fields of your driven classes to the `initialCustomField` as embedded object and get them in your view